# Sending string as text to function POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the next function : 
`func2(text a, text b)`

I have another function func1. In func1 I summon func2 : PERFORM func2('aa',b).
b is a text variable that I initialize.

I get the next error : function func2(unkown,text) does not exist.

any help ? Is there a way to convery string to text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly cast your String to Text by calling the function with

```
 func2('aa' :: TEXT,b)
```